# Issue with Internet explorer 8

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have designed a web page in ASP.Net. And ran it in IE 8. Than changed the zoom size into 400%. Then changed it into 100%. Now the size(Height) of the dropdownboxes in the page has got affected. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

The user should be able to close IE, reopen it, and browse to the site and it should be fine.

If the problem is still there, try it IE8 from a different computer.

If a problem is still there with sizing, then it's most probably the code itself and has nothing to do with the browser.

Comment: It happens in all the pages which contains drop down boxes. Not only in my page

Comment: Sounds like you're out of luck then, as it is an IE8 issue not an issue with your site. I'd suspect if people get this bad result on any website when using IE8, they will know how to deal with it or not use zoom at all.